# Measure of boundary in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I saw that the measure of the boundary of a regular open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is zero, so how can we talk about the integral on this boundary (for me it must be equal to zero always )? I saw that in Sobolev spaces, Green formula, etc.)

Comment: The *$n$-dimensional* measure is zero. What about the $n-1$-dimensional measure?

Comment: i did not really understand you , why we have to look to n-1-dimensional measure because we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Because the boundary is an $n-1$-dimensional object. Think of a disk, with boundary a circle.

Answer (score 3):

The integral on the boundary is done with respect to the $n-1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, as the boundary of a regular set in $\mathbb R^n$ is an $n-1$-dimensional object.

For instance, in $\mathbb R^2$, the boundary of a disk is a circle, which has zero area (i.e. $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure), but positive length (i.e. $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure).

Comment: For example Green's theorem where an integral over a 2-d surface is equal to an integral over the  3-d interior.

Comment: @ Silvia Ghinassi thank you for unswering, i understood well your idea, but do you think so that in green formula the measure is on n-1-dimension because here i am confused

Comment: Yes, the two integrals that appear in the Green formula are with respect two different measures (one is $n$-dim, one is $n-1$). See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), for example.